# Skipped line in `\iftoggle` gives error: paragraph ended and too many }'s

Tags: errors, xparse, etoolbox

I'm trying to make a new command that outputs the first or the second argument depending on a toggle (with a specific counter -- it's basically to output question and answer for an exam).

However, if there is an empty line in either the answer or question, the command fails and gives the error:

```latex
Runaway argument? {
Paragraph ended before \QR was complete.
Too many }'s. }
```

The MWE is:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{listings}

% Make toggle for teacher and student version of file
\newtoggle{corrige}
\togglefalse{corrige}
\newcommand{\cswitch}[2]{
    \iftoggle{corrige}{%
        #1%
    }{%
        #2%
    }%
}

% Make a fancy QR command
\newcounter{qrIndex} % compteur pour les questions
\newcounter{qrIndexSaved}
\newcommand{\save}{\setcounter{qrIndexSaved}{\theqrIndex}}
\newcommand{\retrieve}{\setcounter{qrIndex}{\theqrIndexSaved}}
\newcommand{\resetQ}{\setcounter{qrIndex}{1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\QR}{mm}{%
    \begin{enumerate}[start=\theqrIndex]
      \stepcounter{qrIndex}
        \cswitch{\item #2}{\item #1}%
    \end{enumerate}%
}

\begin{document}

\toggletrue{corrige}

Test switch corrige~: \cswitch{corrige}{enonce}

\bigbreak

Test QR~:

\resetQ
\QR{Q1}{A1}

\QR{
    Q2
  }{
    This has no empty line in either the question or answer.
    \smallbreak
    It works well.
}

\QR{
    Q3
}{

    This \textbf{has} an empty line.
    You'd think it works.
    But error:
    \begin{verbatim}
        Runaway argument? {
        Paragraph ended before \QR was complete.
        Too many }'s. }
    \end{verbatim}
    It only shows the last part of answer, skipping anything before, and messes
    up the enumerate etc, even without the \texttt{toggletrue\{corrige\}}!
}

\end{document}
```

My guess is that it's coming from the `\iftoggle` command and/or the expansion of the second argument with `xparse` in the `NewDocumentCommand`, but I failed to find similar cases online.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `m` arguments do not accept paragraphs, you need `+m` for empty lines to work. The second error comes because you cannot pass `verbatim` as argument to a macro. Last, in order to pass the value of a counter you should use `\value{counter}`, not `\thecounter` (it's working here out of sheer luck).

Comment: `\begin{verbatim}` you can not  use `verbatim` in the argument of another command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX distinguishes between long macros (declared by `\long\def`), whose parameters accept empty lines, and short ones (declared by `\def`). For a quirk of history the LaTeX macro `\newcommand` creates `\long` macros by default, and you need the starred form `\newcommand*` to make short ones. On the other hand, `m` arguments from `xparse` are again short by default, and you need the `+m` specifier to allow empty lines in a macro argument.

Note also that counter values should be passed by means of `\value{counter}`, not `\thecounter`. You're lucky in this situation, because `\thecounter` defaults to the arabic representation, but you shouldn't rely on that.

Last but not least, the `verbatim` environment has never worked as argument of some other macro.

Now you *could* fix these things and make this work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Make toggle for teacher and student version of file
\newtoggle{corrige}
\togglefalse{corrige}
\newcommand{\cswitch}[2]{%
    \iftoggle{corrige}{%
        #1%
    }{%
        #2%
    }%
}

% Make a fancy QR command
\newcounter{qrIndex} % compteur pour les questions
\newcounter{qrIndexSaved}
\newcommand{\save}{\setcounter{qrIndexSaved}{\value{qrIndex}}}
\newcommand{\retrieve}{\setcounter{qrIndex}{\value{qrIndexSaved}}}
\newcommand{\resetQ}{\setcounter{qrIndex}{1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\QR}{+m+m}{% or simply \newcommand{\QR}[2]
    \begin{enumerate}[start=\value{qrIndex}]
      \stepcounter{qrIndex}
        \cswitch{\item #2}{\item #1}%
    \end{enumerate}%
}

\begin{document}

\toggletrue{corrige}

Test switch corrige~: \cswitch{corrige}{enonce}

\bigbreak

Test QR~:

\resetQ
\QR{Q1}{A1}

\QR{
    Q2
  }{
    This has no empty line in either the question or answer.
    \smallbreak
    It works well.
}

\QR{
    Q3
}{

    This \textbf{has} an empty line, and it works.
}

\end{document}
```

However, as you are using `enumitem`, why don't exploit its features? You can define a new list which is automatically resumed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Make toggle for teacher and student version of file
\newtoggle{corrige}
\togglefalse{corrige}
\newcommand{\cswitch}[2]{\iftoggle{corrige}{#1}{#2}}

% Make a fancy QR command
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{resume,label=\arabic{mylisti}.}
\newcommand{\resetQ}{\restartlist{mylist}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\QR}{+m+m}{%
   \begin{mylist}
      \item\cswitch{#2}{#1}%
   \end{mylist}%
}

\begin{document}

\toggletrue{corrige}
\QR{Q1}{A1}
\QR{Q2}{A2}
\QR{Q3}{A3}

\togglefalse{corrige}
\resetQ
\QR{QQ1}{AA1}
\QR{QQ2}{AA2}
\QR{QQ3}{AA3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! It's indeed more concise to use a specific list, I'll add that to my LaTeX tips & tricks. Useful to know that `xparse` is included in `etoolbox` (it might be added in your answer for completion).

Comment: @NoraNICOLAS No, `xparse` isn't included in `etoolbox`, it's included in the LaTeX kernel (since 2020 or so).